# Java Flight Recorder: Recording data as a byte array

Tags: java, jfr

[`Recording`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jfr/jdk/jfr/Recording.html) allows to save recorded data into file using `dump()` method (as shown in example below copied from the javadoc). Is there a way how to get such recorded data in form of `byte[]`.

Preferably without external dependencies. I'm aware of implementing custom in-memory [`FileSystem`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html).

```
   Configuration c = Configuration.getConfiguration("default");
   Recording r = new Recording(c);
   r.start();
   System.gc();
   Thread.sleep(5000);
   r.stop();
   r.dump(Files.createTempFile("my-recording", ".jfr"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for [`getStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/jdk.jfr/jdk/jfr/Recording.html#getStream(java.time.Instant,java.time.Instant))?  That's the only API on `Recording` that might possibly suggest a way to do it.  Other than that, you'll pretty much have to use `dump` to a `Path`, either to an in-memory filesystem or maybe even to an actual temporary file.

Comment: But beware, Recording::getStream() will not work on a in-memory recording. Data must always be on disk. The javadoc for JDK 17 to make this clear.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.jfr/jdk/jfr/Recording.html#getStream(java.time.Instant,java.time.Instant).